# How to do proper data binding in Grails

Tags: grails, data-binding

I'm trying to do standard flow with adding entity to DB. Flow should look like this:

1. User opens link *example.co/connection/putForm*
2. edit all fields
3. submit (POST) to *example.co/connection/put*
4. if no errors then he is redirected to *../conncetion/index* otherwise he should see previous form with all fields filled (step 2) and error message

For now my code looks like this:

```
def putForm() {
    [
            providers: Provider.findAll(),
            cities   : City.findAll()
    ]
}

@Transactional
def put() {
    // not important part of parsing fields from params
    def provider = Provider.get(params.provider)
    def startTime = parseStartTime(params)
    def path = parsePath(params)
    def departurePlace = params.departurePlace

    def connection = new Connection(provider: provider, startTime: startTime, departurePlace: departurePlace, path: path)
    if (connection.save()) {
        redirect controller: 'connection', action: 'index', params: [addedConnection: connection.id] // this part is OK
    } else {
        render view: 'putForm', params: params, model: [connection: connection] // this sucks... look below
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to render view *putForm* but from link *.../connection/put*. This cause problem that after this render all text fields are empty (step 4 above). Also I have ugly link.

Does Grails has any pattern for this common situation?

PS I cannot use scaffolding.

Comment: Its hard to give a definitive answer since its all speculation without seeing the full content of put + putForm. What happens if you render view 'put' (itself) does the fields show up then ? If so is it a 100% that the value definitions in both put and putForm are identical  try doing a test of changing the pages and also adding ${params} ----<br> ${connection} ---- <br> at the top of both pages .. review their output if identical then its an issue on your putForm gsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not that far off.. try this:

```
def putForm() {
    [
            providers: Provider.findAll(),
            cities   : City.findAll(),
connection: new Connection()  // everything defaulted to empty or whatever you want the default to be
    ]
}

@Transactional
def put( Connection connection ) {
    // NOTE: by putting the connection as the parameter to this action,
    // all params.X that match a property X in the connection will auto-
    // populate, even the Provider, assuming the value of params.provider.id
    // is the id of a provider or blank (in which case 
    // connection.provider will be null.

    // Skip this now
    //def provider = Provider.get(params.provider)
    //def startTime = parseStartTime(params)
    //def path = parsePath(params)
    //def departurePlace = params.departurePlace
    //def connection = new Connection(provider: provider, 
    // startTime: startTime, departurePlace: departurePlace, path: path)

    if (connection.save()) {
        redirect controller: 'connection', action: 'index', 
           params: [addedConnection: connection.id] // this part is OK
    } else {
        render view: 'putForm', model: [
            providers: Provider.findAll(),
            cities   : City.findAll(),
            connection: connection] 
    }
}
```

The thing you need now is to make sure your putForm.gsp actually uses the values you sent down.  You should put in things like:

```
<g:input name="path" type="text" 
         value="${fieldValue( bean:connection, field:'path' )}" />
```

and

```
<g:select name="provider.id" from="${providers}"   // note the .id in places here
          value="${connection.provider?.id ?: ''}"
          noSelection="['':'None']"/>
```

Note that these will populate with whatever is in the connection sent down each time the page is rendered.  So the first time it'll just have the default values, and if it has to rerender due to errors, it'll have the connection values that failed validation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Grails is great framework but you need to know all the patterns :D